# Unable to scroll to bottom with different table cell heights in RATreeView Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

I am using a library ([RATreeView](https://github.com/Augustyniak/RATreeView))

I have a perfectly working table that can expand the way I want it to, but I have the requirement to have different heights on certain sections, this seems to cause the table's height to not change in some way (regarding the scrollable surface of the UIView its added to).

So when I expand sections they allow me to scroll further down, that still works, but I am unable to see all the cells; as if the UIView or table is unable to scroll all the way. The cells differentiating heights are no problem, that comes out perfectly. I also can confirm that it does not have to do with the tab bar being on top of the content either.

```
- (CGFloat)treeView:(RATreeView*)treeView heightForRowForItem:(id)item {
    SomeObject* levelObject = item;

    if (levelObject.isChild == YES) {
        if ([levelObject.type isEqualToString:@"fatty"]) {
            return 140;
        }

        return 50;
    }

    return 60;
}
```

As you can see I set the height based on the type of the object, and whether or not it is supposed to be a section header (a child or parent). So this seems to break the RATreeView and so far unfortunately I cannot solve it. Maybe someone else has.

If any more detail is required I can elaborate.

Comment: So the problem was that the way I was initialising the TreeView was wrong, I set it's frame to that of the self.view, which I thought would only be that of the current ViewController it was on, but I had my ViewController nested in a CollectionViewController and it was getting the entire height of the screen (the CollectionViewController). 

So it was just up to me to check that I deduct the top View Controller's size from the CollectionViewController. if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

When initialising subviews onto a view, always ensure the height you are working with is that which you think it is. I made a simple mistake that I *assumed* that I was working with the height of the ViewController I was currently on when in fact **self.view.frame.size.height** was giving me the height of the entire CollectionViewController (The entire screen). So just deduct the size of the TabBarController and the height of the ViewControllers that are also on the screen and viola, you have the correct height.